# Expanding a summation of covariant derivatives

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, covariance

I hope this is not a silly question but I am trying to understand how this part of the equation works:

$$
\nabla_{\lambda} \left( \nabla_{\mu}(R_{\nu \lambda}) + \nabla_{\nu}(R_{\mu \lambda}) \right)
$$

Where $R_{xx}$ is the Ricci tensor.

My question: Am I required to work out the covariant derivatives separate then work out the 'outer' covariant derivative of the result **or** should I use the double covariant derivative rule twice like so:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_a \nabla_b h_{cd} &= \partial_a ( \partial_b h_{cd} - \Gamma^f_{bc} h_{fd} - \Gamma^f_{bd} h_{cf}  )  \\
&\qquad \qquad - \Gamma^e_{ab} ( \partial_e h_{cd} - \Gamma^f_{ec} h_{fd} - \Gamma^f_{ed} h_{cf} )  \\
&\qquad \qquad - \Gamma^e_{ac} ( \partial_b h_{ed} - \Gamma^f_{be} h_{fd} - \Gamma^f_{bd} h_{ef} ) \\
&\qquad \qquad  - \Gamma^e_{ad} ( \partial_b h_{ce} - \Gamma^f_{bc} h_{fe} - \Gamma^f_{be} h_{cf} ) 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think the result is a tensor, which is a vector space homomorphism I believe, so both ways should be the same?

Comment: My Mathematica code is generating different results that's why. I am trying to derive the components of the field equations for $f(G)$ gravity

Comment: If they are not a homomorphism, I would say the inner covariant derivatives first, then the plus, then the outer covariant derivative, then the trace over lambda. Oh wait a moment, the lambdas are doubly indexed covariant? Is that a bug?

Comment: Lamda is a free index in this instance

Comment: what Mathematica package are you using, if any ?

Comment: None, I have heard about xAct however I am quite reluctant to try it. Do you think I should opt for a package?

Comment: Mark, this conversation is not really helpful. Can you please rethink about what it is that bothers you and edit the question accordingly?

Comment: Answered my question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that yes it is homomorphism and one can simply expand the brackets accordingly.

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_a \nabla_b h_{cd} &= \partial_a ( \partial_b h_{cd} - \Gamma^f_{bc} h_{fd} - \Gamma^f_{bd} h_{cf}  )  \\
&\qquad \qquad - \Gamma^e_{ab} ( \partial_e h_{cd} - \Gamma^f_{ec} h_{fd} - \Gamma^f_{ed} h_{cf} )  \\
&\qquad \qquad - \Gamma^e_{ac} ( \partial_b h_{ed} - \Gamma^f_{be} h_{fd} - \Gamma^f_{bd} h_{ef} ) \\
&\qquad \qquad  - \Gamma^e_{ad} ( \partial_b h_{ce} - \Gamma^f_{bc} h_{fe} - \Gamma^f_{be} h_{cf} ) 
\end{align}
$$

May be used in this instance